# shutil.move() creates duplicates and fails on subsequent calls

Tags: python, shutil

I finished writing a script which creates some files so I'm making a `tidy()` function which sorts these files in folders. The end result should look like this:

```
/Scripting
- Output
- script.py

/Scripting/Output
- Folder1
- Folder2
- Folder3

Each folder contains the necessary files
```

I managed to create the list of folders and get the files in them without any problem so I now have in `/Project`: `script.py`, `folder1`, `folder2`, etc... I copy pasted most of the code from the first part in order to move them into the `Output` folder. The following code is executed with every subfolder containing their respective files is located in the same directory as the script.

```
try:
    os.mkdir('output')
except FileExistsError:
    pass
for file in os.listdir():
    if '.' not in file and file != 'output':
        shutil.move(file, f'{os.getcwd()}/output/{file})
```

The problem is that if I look into my folder after running, I find the following directory tree:

```
/Output
- Folder1
    - Folder1
    - File1
    - File2
```

I get a duplicate folder within that folder and I don't understand where it's coming from. If I try to call the script again, I get the error: `shutil.Error destination path 'Scripting/output/folder1/fodler1' already exists`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Here's the new code:

```
try:
    os.mkdir('output')
except FileExistsError:
    pass
obj = os.scandir()
cwd = os.getcwd()
for entry in obj:
    if entry.is_dir() and not entry.name.startswith('.'):
        continue
        shutil.move(entry.name, f'{cwd}/'/output/'{entry.name}')
```

This works the first time I run it, but breaks if I keep calling the script by giving me the same mistake as above. It creates folder1 within folder1 only on subsequent calls and I can't find a reason for it.

Comment: You may want to use `os.scandir` instead of `os.listdir`, and then check the `is_dir` attribute on each `os.DirEntry` object in the returned iterator, so that you don't `move` the directories but only the files

Comment: @gimix this does make the code better and it works the first time I call it (updated code in post). It just keeps breaking the same way as before if I call it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer mostly by trial and error. I initially chose to use shutil.move() because it replaces a **file** if it finds another one with the same name. However, it does not do this with directory. It will instead add to that path. `/Scripting/Output/Folder1/` as a destination path for Folder1 would give an error when I run the script a second time so instead of replacing the folder, it simple adds it into its path which would then become `/Scripting/Output/Folder1/Folder1/` while still adding the files to the initial path (it looks like it runs the shutil.move() on everything within that path). To fix this, use `obj = os.scandir()` with `obj.is_dir()` and `obj.name` to parse your folders. Either `os.rmdir()` the extra folder every time, or add the folders before adding the files. This is the code that worked for me:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
try:
    os.mkdir('output')
except:
    pass
os.chdir('output')
for name in folder_names:
    try:
        os.mkdir(name)
    except:
        pass
os.chdir('..')
obj = os.scandir()
cwd = os.getcwd()
for f in obj:
    if f.is_file():
        if True:# depends on how your files are organized
            shutil.move(f.name, f'{cwd}/output/folder1/{f.name}')
        # Do this for every file
```